# Get data from product and shop functionality

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I´m starting with prestashop 1.5 and i´m creating a module where will appears: Two Featured Products and Four products on offer.

I have already create the module (.php .tpl) basic files and i can get the products id, but i don´t know how to get the data of that products (title, image, description and price).

This is my code:

module.php

```
    public function obtenerDestacados(){

        $sql = 'SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product';
        $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
        return $results;

    }
```

module.tpl

```
{foreach iniciallou::obtenerDestacados() as $prod}
        {$prod['id_product']}

        <br />
{/foreach}
```

How i can do something like the homeFeaturedProducts module from 0?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you not to create custom functions, if in case you are making something very specific, since there is a lot of SQL JOINS going on in prestashop tables.

You've suggested homefeatured module, why not to grab products exactly like the module?

I currently have the hf module customized, so I can not tell you the original code, albeit take look at prestashop class files, and use created methods for grabbing products, like mostly used Category::getProducts, or Product::getProducts (parameters look up in the methods definitions in class files)